# Grabbing JSON data from API with multi-threaded requests

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm using httparty for making requests and currently have the following code:

```
def scr(users)
  users.times do |id|
    test_url =  "siteurl/#{id}"
    Thread.new do     
      response = HTTParty.get(test_url)

      open('users.json', 'a') do |f|
        f.puts "#{response.to_json}, "
      end
      p "added"
    end
  end
  sleep    
end
```

It works OK for 100-300 records.

I tried adding `Thread.exit` after `sleep`, but if I set users to something like 200000, after a while my terminal throws an error. I don't remember what it was but it's something about threads... resource is busy but some records. (About 10000 were added successfully.)

It looks like I'm doing it wrong and need to somehow break requests to batches.

---

**up**

here's what I got:

```
def scr(users)
 threads = []
 urls = []

 users.times do |id|
   test_url = "site_url/#{id}"
   urls<<test_url
 end

  urls.each_slice(8) do |batch|
    batch.each do |t|
      threads << Thread.new do
        response = HTTParty.get(t)
        response.to_json
      end
    end 
  end   

 all_values = threads.map {|t| t.value}.join(', ')
 open('users.json', 'a') do |f|
  f.puts all_values
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On quick inspection, the problem would seem to be that you have a race condition with regards to your JSON file. Even if you don't get an error, you'll definitely get corrupted data.

The simplest solution is probably just to do all the writing at the end:

```
  def scr(users)
   threads = []
   users.times do |id|
     test_url =  "siteurl/#{id}"
     threads << Thread.new do     
       response = HTTParty.get(test_url)
       response.to_json
     end
   end
   all_values = threads.map {|t| t.value}.join(', ')
   open('users.json', 'a') do |f|
    f.puts all_values
   end
  end
```

Wasn't able to test that, but it should do the trick. It's also better in general to be using `Thread#join` or `Thread#value` instead of `sleep`.

Comment: this throws `Too many open files - socket(2) for "site_url" port 443` but I guess this is not the code problem.

Comment: @railsr: I should have thought of that. Yes, you do have to rate limit. Hold on -- I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @railsr: I don't have time to actually write the code right now, but the gist of it is that you have *n* threads (say, 4, or 8) each of which, in sequence does 1/*n*th of the tasks. Then you collect the results like the above code.